# How to send data from activity to the fragment for update a graph?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-graphview

```
public class GraphUpdate extends Fragment {
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mTimer;
    private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> mSeries;
    private double graph2LastXValue = 5d;
    private int value;
    private String TAG = "FRAGMENT";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
        mSeries = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
        graph.addSeries(mSeries);
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(40);

        return rootView;
   }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        mTimer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
                graph2LastXValue += 1d;
                mSeries.appendData(new DataPoint(graph2LastXValue, value), true, 40);
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }

        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer, 300);
     }
```

I have to update this graph with the data of my Main_Activity.

MainActivity at runtime send some data to my Fragment.
GraphUpdate update the graph with the data.

what is the best way? I have read how to send the data from activity to fragment with Interface or Bundle, but for keep updated the graph what the best solution is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send data from activity to fragment in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just create a method in fragment which actually update your graph .and using fragment object from your activity call update graph method which you already declare in fragment simple.e.x.

```
frag=(cast)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment tag");
frag.updateGraph() from your activity. 
and declare updateGraph method in fragment.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, create a method in your GraphUpdate class called updateFragment(). Then, call the method from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use interface also just write one public method in that fragment. just call that method. if you want to send data use the method will arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler with post delay of your choice in your fragment and call your required method in your activity, get data and update your graph, for continues update use post delay inside your runable